# replacing article or basic page image with video

Tags: media

How can I replace the main image at an article  or a basic page with a video?
I used the Video Embed Field module but it only embeds the video in the body.
What I need is the video to be in the place of the main image, not in the body of the content.

Answer (score 0):

1. Here is a standard front page. The teaser view. I think this is what you see and where you would like to see the video instead of the image.

[image: node teaser default]

2. This seems like what you would like. On the preview, add the video.

[image: node teaser with video]

3. This is the full node view. As you can see, the full text is here.

[image: full node view]

4. When you go to the content type `admin/structure/types/manage/article/display` the default display is the full node view

[image: default field display view]

5. On the teaser display, `/admin/structure/types/manage/article/display/teaser` (this is for the article content type). At the top right it says teaser.

Here you need to add the *"Embed field"*. By default it was hidden.

You can move the image to hidden if you want.

[image: teaser field display view]

And with this you get the image from the second screenshot.

I think that's what you want/need.

---

**Original answer. Updated above based on comments.**

If you want to upload, instead of embed, the video module has the option,

https://www.drupal.org/project/video

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No, I don't want to upload, I just want to replace the main image of an article with a video, so when I go on the front page I see the video instead of the image at the image's place.How can I do that?

Comment: For the Video Embed field check the display options of the field. It may need to be changed. The url should be `/admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENT_TYPE/display` where `CONTENT_TYPE` is the machine name of your content (`page` or `article`) for the defaults.

Comment: Thank you. I did check the display options, the video field exists there. However, when I add the url of the video when I add content and leave the main image field blank without uploading a picture, then on the front end all I get is the video in the body of the content and no picture. What I need is the video to appear in the place of the image.I don't know if I am explaining well enough.I hope it is clear.

Comment: Could you update the question with screenshots of what you are seeing? I think the following would be ideal: field page, field configuration, content type display, where you are seeing the image and body. Obviously anything else you see would be great.

Comment: @kyriakib I updated my answer. Let me know if that's what you need.

Comment: Thank you very very much. I appreciate your help and solutions. I will try again and let you know. Thanks again.